# Saved map fro Slam_toolbox won't show up in RViz

Tags: ros2, slam, mapping, ros-humble, lidar

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaiA3hWaRzE&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&index=17) and he is able to load his saved map back into RViz with no issues but when I do the exact same thing I just get an empty map? Not really sure what I am doing wrong and I haven't been able to find an answer for a similar problem from my research.

After launching gazebo, RViz2 and my teleopkeyboard script I also run Slam_toolbox with the following command:

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py file_params:=./src/ford_bot/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml use_sim_time:=true
```

[Link to my yaml file](https://github.com/balen-muon/ford_bot/blob/main/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml)

Answer (score 1):

copy the launch file "online_async_launch.py" from "slam_toolbox" into your robot package launch directory, change the package name to your robot package name, and launch it from your robot package workspace.

Comment: That sounds like it will work but might not be the best way to do this. There's potentially an issue with the paths or something else potentially at issue.